# Array con Datos JS desde Archivo/xls

Tags: javascript, array

Tengo un archivo xls (Excel) con parroquias y tengo que importarlas y hacer arrays en javascript, 
Como podría hacerlo?

De momento lo unico que se me ocurrió fué convertir el archivo xls a txt
pero tengo un monton de info que no me hace falta.

Comment: ¿Has intentado algo? Simplemente con buscar en google te aparecen mogollón de opciones para hacerlo.

Comment: Sii, pero no se como parsear primero lo que me sobra antes y después

Comment: A que te refieres con "parsear lo que te sobra"? Por favor amplia la pregunta.

Comment: A que tengo un excel con 9 columnas y no se como cojer los datos de la que me interesa desde javascript y hacer arrays

Answer (score 0):

Y por qué usar XLS, te quedaría más fácil convertirlo a CSV.
Y con FileReader() puedes leer el archivo y recorrerlo.

Ejemplo:

```
var reader = new FileReader();
reader.onload = function() {
    var filas = reader.result.split("\n");
    for(var i in filas) {
       var columnas = filas[i].split(",");
       console.log("Fila " + i + ": ", columnas);
    }
};

file.readAsDataURL(archivoBlob);
```

Eso te puede servir. Donde "archivoBlob" puede ser un archivo seleccionado en un input[type=file].

Comment: Te comparto la documentación: https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/FileReader/readAsDataURL

Comment: Muchas gracias, es que no sabía como hacerlo, y necesitaba un camino por donde tirar

Comment: Hola de nuevo no consigo hacerlo funcionar, no se que hago mal, haber si me puedes echar una mano

Comment: Comparte tu código y te ayudo. Saludos.